# How to set up, maintain and distribute a template VM in VMware

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

(i posted this question on VMware community forums, with no response)

All of my developers use VMware workstation 11 for running their Visual Studio development environments in Windows. I originally created a base VM, and then simply shared it around to all the users, unbeknown to all the issues it would cause with computer name conflicts, joining the domain, etc. Apparently I didn't 'sysprep' it. Someone with some VMware knowledge tried to help me out to set it up, but im still not sure if it is 100% correct.

I am now at a point where I need to make changes/updates to the base VM (new VS, run Windows Updates, etc) and distribute a new one around to all the developers again, and I need some help to make sure I do it properly this time:

1. I have 2 VM images currently: 1) a ‘base’ one that opens up to this screen http://screencast.com/t/tBO0IUvwtpbY  and 2) one that opens up to this screen http://screencast.com/t/DLV71PeNygrk  . I’m assuming it is the ‘base’ one that I make the ‘edits’ to?
2. If I do edit the ‘base’ VM, what option(s) should I choose in that sys prep dialog?
3. Once I make the necessary updates to the base VM, what do I need to do to 'prepare' it for distribution to my developers (do I need to run sys prep, do I need to make a copy of VM beforehand, etc)?
4. Currently the VM has 2 HD's: 1) used for the OS and applications (Persistent and non-Independent), and 2) used to store data files (Persistent and Independent) . Is this the best way to set it up and use the VM (and then use 'snapshots' to revert back to previous states), or should the OS disk be set up as 'non-persistent' after the user has set up the VM for first use (i.e. joined the domain, set up VS Workspace, etc) ? Basically we have had a few scenarios recently where the OS and VS have been corrupted and it took the devs a while to fix it, so I want them to have some sort of way to revert back to a known clean working  state.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your questions you are on the right track.

1. the first screen that opens is correct, customise everything you require in the OS then run the OOBE before distribution
2. Choose OOBE and tick Generalise, then choose shutdown.
3. Once the VM is shutdown export it and pass it round your developers. they will need to complete the wizard and then join to the domain if required, this will ensure all the sids are different on each server, remember they must still change the Servers name before joining the domain
4. Snapshots are best, if your dev needs to reboot etc he doesn't want to loose his changes, he then has the option to revert to a snapshot.

Hopefully this has answered your question, let me know if there is anything else you need :)